# Asp.net core app random route stops working until i recycle app pool

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are experiencing an odd issue with our production webserver.

Random route from our app stops working, and this is the error we find in our app insights log.
It's always just one route, but never the same. 
Issue disappears after we recycle app pool

We are using asp.net core 2.0.1 with .net framework.

Any ideas regarding this issue?

```
System.IO.IOException:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.IO.FileStream.EndRead (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Read (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.StreamSourceDocument.ComputeChecksum (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.StreamSourceDocument..ctor (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorSourceDocument.ReadFrom (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorSourceDocument.ReadFrom (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorTemplateEngine.CreateCodeDocument (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.MvcRazorTemplateEngine.CreateCodeDocument (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorTemplateEngine.CreateCodeDocument (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=2.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CompileAndEmit (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler.CreateCacheEntry (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorPageFactoryProvider.CreateFactory (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.CreateCacheResult (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.OnCacheMiss (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper+<RenderPartialCoreAsync>d__60.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper+<PartialAsync>d__57.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperPartialExtensions.Partial (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlHelperPartialExtensions.Partial (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at AspNetCore._Areas_Mobile_Views_Timeline_Index_cshtml+<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext (jasjbnoj.s3b, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nulljasjbnoj.s3b, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\Webovi\index_new\Areas\Mobile\Views\Timeline\Index.cshtmljasjbnoj.s3b, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 48)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderPageCoreAsync>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderPageAsync>d__15.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView+<RenderAsync>d__14.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__21.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult+<ExecuteResultAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeResultAsync>d__19.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
```

Comment: Can you show us how you configure routing in the app, and the routes that are throwing the errors? It might be as simple as setting up the routing middleware to handle these routes.

Comment: @train do you think that is necessary, since random route throws an error on random web server? It's not always the same, and the issue disappears after we recycle app pool. It reappears randomly

Comment: Possibly, you may need to specify the filter path to determine what it should look at and pass to Kestrel for processing in the config files. It won't hurt to show us your config files and start up.

Comment: Also the url's, doesn't have to be the exact url but you can give us an example of the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to update to asp.net core 2.2, but that did not help.

Then I read that the asp.net core team removed the need for kestrel in 2.2, so I decided to switch to in-process hosting by adding  `.UseIIS()` in my builder.

Not sure exactly why, but problem disappeared after that.